# scrollPanel doesn't show the thumb on image only

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jscrollbar

I have ImageComponent class created to display the image, however when I call it from other class, scrollPanel does not display thumb, hence I cannot scroll up or down and left or right. It works fine with JButton, JTextField. So I am guessing the problem with my ImageComponent class?`

```
class ImageComponent extends JComponent {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Image image;

    public ImageComponent() {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File(
                    "/Users/Martynas/Downloads/photos/dscf1533.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // paint image
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
}
```

this is the class where I am initialising and calling ImageComponent class:

```
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Component component = new ImageComponent();

    JScrollPane scrollPanel = new JScrollPane(component, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    frame.add(scrollPanel);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default preferred size of any component is always `0x0`.  The scroll pane will use this information to determine how best to display your component and if the scroll bars are required or not

In your `ImageComponent` class, you should consider overriding the `getPreferredSize` method

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {  
    return image == null ? super.getPreferredSize() : new Dimension(image.getWidth(this), image.getHeight(this));
}
```

There's, also, never any need for your `paintComponent` method to public, there never should be a need for anybody else to call it.

You should also pass `this` as the reference to the `ImageObserver` parameter for `drawImage`...

```
g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
```

This is more important for images loaded via other means then `ImageIO`, but is good practice.

Having said all that, you should consider having a look at `JLabel`, as it's designed to display images out of the box.  Have a look at [How to use labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) for more details

Comment: Did you mean to use Imageicon class?  ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("/Users/Martynas/Downloads/photos/dscf1533.jpg");
  JScrollPane scoll = new JScrollPane(new JLabel(image));
  frame.add(scoll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

Comment: Yep, something like that, unless you had a particular need to custom paint the image